# puzzle for Vietnamese eight-year-olds

Tags: algorithms

I read in the [Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/science/alexs-adventures-in-numberland/2015/may/20/can-you-do-the-maths-puzzle-for-vietnamese-eight-year-olds-that-has-stumped-parents-and-teachers) about a puzzle given to 8-year old in Vietnam.

> Enter the digits 1 to 9 into the following grid so that the equality holds

[image]

Now, given access to a computer, this can be solved easily in a minute or so. My [python solution](https://repl.it/oxA) is 19 lines of codes (8 of which is indentation).

What I'm interested in is whether there is a general algorithm better than the brute force for solving problems such as this one. My code found 136 solutions out of 9! = 362,880 possible arrangements of 1-9. So, is there a strategy better than randomly finding a solution once in ~2403 (362,880/136) attempts. In other words, if you were given this problem in Putnam, how would you approach it.

edit: assume regular order of operations, i.e. the "snake" plays no role

Comment: Do the normal order of operations rules apply, or is it strictly following the operations in order of the path?  I'm just not familiar with problems written in snake format!

Comment: It would surprise me, if there is anything better than brute force. The only operations where restrictions might be possible, are the divisons.

Comment: An algorithm really sounds interesting

Comment: The problem would be more attractive, if the solution would be unique. Of course, this would make the problem very difficult, if it must be solved by hand.

Comment: To be honest, I'm more interested in a possible way to approach it than speculating about the role of the snake ...

Comment: @Shane "it feels like there should be a way to solve it backwards" D you mean something like Dynamic programming?

Comment: @quapka I was thinking more like something analogous to backward induction to find a subgame perfect Nash equilibrium -- my dumb economist brain would only turn to DP if the problem were infinite and I were looking for a fixed point, but perhaps there's a way to formulate this as such. With the new edit, that the snake doesn't define the order of operations, this now seems less likely to be fruitful.

Comment: @Paul According to the algorithm scibuff provided the operations evaluate by the [priority](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html) as usual. Also it is stated in the Guardian article: **following the order of operations - multiply first, then division, addition and subtraction last**.

Comment: @Shane Citing the article again: _UPDATE: For those who were stumped by the symbols, the colon “:” is the division sign. Now return to your workings..._

Comment: @quapka Thanks. I did see those subsequently and hence deleted the comment.

Comment: @DavidK thanks, I searched but would have never guessed that title (or those tags)